particle system rotation is not working

I just added a new object and added hair. And after turning on the advanced, I checked the rotation. And changed orientation axis to global z. That's all I did. But the direction of the hair isn't looking up. Why does it work like this?

I'm not sure you can orientate the curve hair with the Rotation settings (rather for the Object type of hair), but you can either:

Play with the Velocity parameters:



Create a Force  Field (strong enought):



Comb the hair in Particle Edit mode:


